# Euler Characteristic of a blowing up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, blowup

I'm trying to compute the Euler Characteristic of the blowing up of  $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ at $n$ points. Does anyone know how could I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Euler characteristic? $\chi(\mathcal{O})$ is a birational invariant, so you mean something else?

Answer (score 7):

I thought I'd write down a couple of thoughts about how we can obtain the result $\chi_{\rm top}(Bl_n(\mathbb P^2)) = 3 + n$ explained in Nicolas' answer.

**Method 1**:

[Noether's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem_for_surfaces#Noether's_formula) for surfaces states that
$$\chi(\mathcal O_X)= \tfrac 1 {12}\left( K_X.K_X + \chi_{\rm top}(X)\right)$$
where $\chi(\mathcal O_X)$ denotes the holomorphic Euler characteristic of the structure sheaf, $K_X . K_X$ denotes the self-intersection of the canonical divisor, and $\chi_{\rm top}(X)$ denotes the topological Euler characteristic of the space (with the analytic topology).

We also have the following two facts (both of which are proved in Beauville's Complex Algebraic Surfaces):

- As Mohan pointed out, $\chi(\mathcal O_X)$ is a birational invariant, so if $\pi : \widetilde X \to X$ is a blow-up, then $\chi(\mathcal O_{\widetilde X}) = \chi(\mathcal O_X)$.
- The self-intersection of the canonical class of the blow-up is related to the self-intersection of the original space by $K_{\widetilde X}.K_{\widetilde X}=\pi^\star K_X . \pi^\star K_X - 1$.

Combining all of these observations, we see that blowing up a surface at a point increases the topological Euler characteristic $\chi_{\rm top}(X)$ by one.

**Method 2:**

I think this method is really equivalent to  Nicolas' answer...

I believe that complex quasi-projective varieties obey an [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) (see also [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wpa6CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=inclusion%20exclusion%20principle%20euler%20characteristic%20variety&source=bl&ots=f7PhKMKBio&sig=ek5-UaHZpxmKSvgdATeOHD7LJ5E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwishcLHuuLbAhXIKcAKHaADDS8Q6AEIaTAG#v=onepage&q=inclusion%20exclusion%20principle%20euler%20characteristic%20variety&f=false)): if $X$ is a complex projective variety and $Y \subset X$ is a closed subvariety, then
$$ \chi_{\rm top}(X) = \chi_{\rm top}(X \setminus Y) + \chi_{\rm top} (Y)$$
So if you think of the blow-up operation as removing a point ($Y = \{ \rm pt \}$), then adding a two-sphere ($Y = \mathbb {CP}^1$), this formula tells you that the Euler characteristic increases by one after the blow-up.

I must admit I've never studied a proof of this result, but I believe it is based on triangulation.

Comment: Thank you to all of you. Your answers were very useful.

Comment: Great answer ! For the method 2, one can also use the compactly supported Euler characteristic, which is always additive, and coincide with the usual Euler characteristic for compact spaces.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I didn't realise that the compactly supported Euler characteristic always obeys inclusion exclusion with no assumptions required on the spaces! But it's in Wikipedia, so it must be true. Is there some simple Mayer-Vietoris argument to prove this?

Comment: @KennyWong : Yes, there is the Mayer-Vietoris sequence with compact support ! It works for $Z \subset X$ open, giving $$ \dots \to H^q_c(U) \to H^q_c(X) \to H^q_c(Z) \to \dots $$ (where $U = X \backslash Z$). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_with_compact_support
I don't know exactly how to prove it (for the usual Mayer-Vietoris sequence there is a very clean proof using a short exact sequence of sheaves, so maybe the same could apply here ...)

Comment: $Z$ is closed sorry ! And now I think you probably need some conditions on $Z$, because there might be very ugly closed set so the Euler characteristic is not even defined ...

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Great - thanks!

Comment: @KennyWong : You're welcome ! Your first argument is really nice.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that for a complex surface $S$ and $p$ a smooth point, we have $\chi(Bl_{p}S) = \chi(S) +1 $, say using triangulations. This gives $\chi(Bl_{n}(\Bbb{P}^2)) = 3 + n$.

For example, $n=6$ is a cubic hypersurface and you can easily check that you get $9$.